# Run a jar file on Android from code

Tags: java, android, jar

Is it possible to run/execute a .jar file on Android from code especially with Android's shift to ART instead of Dalvik?

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of Android used to come with `DVM (Dalvic Virtual Machine)`, and the newer versions are used to come with `ART (Android Run Time)`.

Both of them execute the .dex (Dalvic Executable).

You cannot run .jar files directly in Android, but you can try some apps or VMs.